# Cannot get DocuSign Connect working with Salesforce: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: salesforce, docusignapi

I'm new to DocuSign and have just been playing around setting up DocuSign for Salesforce. I have a DocuSign demo environment and a Salesforce developer environment. I've installed DocuSign for Salesforce (dfs) and added the "Send to DocuSign" and DocuSign Status items to the page layout of the SF Contract object.

I hit "Send to DocuSign" on a new Contract and after some time this seemed to work, a new DocuSign status was added in the Status section of the Contract. It took a while, so I wanted to set up Connect so that it would be faster, or at least that's how I thought it should work.

I followed the documentation to set up Connect and activated the DocuSign Status Object and Enabled Logging. I then hit "Send to DocuSign" again. The Status section doesn't get updated with any new DocuSign Status objects. The output in the logs says:

```
10/15/2015 10:58:23 AM
Salesforce Connect Config: <sfconfig log="1" ackl="0" password="Idxhauns2N2DyYGT1jEm2Q==" sfenvironment="production" senderselectable="Contract,Lead,Opportunity,Case,Account" senderoverride="0" username="jen@jenscompany.com"><dsevents><dsevent event="Completed" level="Envelope" /><dsevent event="Declined" level="Envelope" /><dsevent event="Delivered" level="Envelope" /><dsevent event="Sent" level="Envelope" /><dsevent event="Signed" level="Envelope" /><dsevent event="Voided" level="Envelope" /><dsevent event="Completed" level="Recipient" /><dsevent event="Declined" level="Recipient" /><dsevent event="Delivered" level="Recipient" /><dsevent event="Sent" level="Recipient" /></dsevents><dsusers all="1"><dsuser userId="78c3e1da-085a-45a0-9bcf-1dcddbc48158" /></dsusers><sfobject object="dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c" objectName="dsfs__DocuSign_Status__c" active="1" insert="1" oncompleteonly="0"><updatefield sffield="dsfs__DocuSign_Envelope_ID__c" dsnode="Envelope" dsattr="EnvelopeId" /><updatefield sffield="dsfs__Sent_Date_Time__c" dsnode="Envelope" dsattr="SentInitial" /><updatefield sffield="dsfs__Sender__c" dsnode="Envelope" dsattr="UserName" /><updatefield sffield="dsfs__Sender_Email__c" dsnode="Envelope" dsattr="Email" /><updatefield sffield="dsfs__Envelope_Status__c" dsnode="Envelope" dsattr="Status" /><updatefield sffield="dsfs__Completed_Date_Time__c" dsnode="Envelope" dsattr="Completed" /><updatefield sffield="dsfs__Subject__c" dsnode="Envelope" dsattr="Subject" /><updatefield sffield="dsfs__Company__r" dsnode="EnvelopeCustomField" dsattr="##SFAccount" /><updatefield sffield="dsfs__Case__r" dsnode="EnvelopeCustomField" dsattr="##SFCase" /><updatefield sffield="dsfs__Contract__r" dsnode="EnvelopeCustomField" dsattr="##SFContract" /><updatefield sffield="dsfs__Opportunity__r" dsnode="EnvelopeCustomField" dsattr="##SFOpportunity" /><updatefield sffield="dsfs__Declined_Date_Time__c" dsnode="Recipient" dsattr="Declined" /><updatefield sffield="dsfs__Declined_Reason__c" dsnode="Recipient" dsattr="DeclineReason" /><updatefield sffield="dsfs__Voided_Date_Time__c" dsnode="Envelope" dsattr="Voided" /><updatefield sffield="dsfs__Voided_Reason__c" dsnode="Envelope" dsattr="VoidedReason" /><updatefield sffield="dsfs__Envelope_Link__c" dsnode="Envelope" dsattr="EnvelopeId" dslink="1" /><updatefield sffield="dsfs__Viewed_Date_Time__c" dsnode="Recipient" dsattr="Delivered" /><updatefield dsnode="##docattachment" dsattr="Document,0,1,NamePDFReplaceExt" /><updatefield sffield="##docattachment" dsnode="##docattachment" dsattr="Document,0,1,NamePDFReplaceExt" dslink="0" /><selectfield sffield="dsfs__DocuSign_Envelope_ID__c" dsnode="Envelope" dsattr="EnvelopeId" /></sfobject></sfconfig>
10/15/2015 10:58:23 AM
Envelope Data: <Certificate><Envelopes><Envelope EnvelopeId="1A7BCB46-E398-41AA-ACD1-18BCD2C1E9C5" AccountId="5CB10BDC-1DAB-4CA7-A2E7-BEB2AEA280CB" UserId="78C3E1DA-085A-45A0-9BCF-1DCDDBC48158" UserName="Jennifer Cheung" Email="striderwho@hotmail.com" SenderIP="182.50.78.8 " SigningLocation="Online" SourceEnvelopeId="" Status="Sent" Created="10/15/2015 10:58:02 AM" CreatedBy="78C3E1DA-085A-45A0-9BCF-1DCDDBC48158" Deleted="" DeletedBy="" ACStatus="Original" ACStatusDate="10/15/2015 10:58:02 AM" ACHolder="Jennifer Cheung" ACHolderEmail="striderwho@hotmail.com" ACHolderLocation="DocuSign" Sent="10/15/2015 10:58:03 AM" SentInitial="10/15/2015 10:58:03 AM" Delivered="" Signed="" Completed="" Declined="" TimedOut="" Voided="" VoidedReason="" Subject="Documents for your DocuSign Signature" AutoNav="Enabled" EnvelopeIdStamping="Enabled"><Owners><Owner ACStatus="Original" ACStatusDate="10/15/2015 10:58:02 AM" ACHolder="Jennifer Cheung" ACHolderEmail="striderwho@hotmail.com" ACHolderLocation="DocuSign" /></Owners></Envelope></Envelopes><Documents><Document DocumentId="FD5B3331-8709-4851-ACC6-2D899252E9FE" Sequence="1" DocumentType="Content" Name="PRIMEDIRECTIVE.pdf" Extension="pdf" Pages="1" Created="10/15/2015 10:58:03 AM" Status="Created" Hash="fLF+/G8FCge71UO2CWj57Glz+Jc=" /></Documents><Pages><Page PageId="99A23D55-B32D-4F89-A6D3-2FE6AEC475E7" DocumentId="FD5B3331-8709-4851-ACC6-2D899252E9FE" PageType="Content" Sequence="1" Status="Active" /></Pages><Tabs /><Recipients><Recipient RecipientId="0DD36920-7E09-4E4D-B108-E8DB4DFCF637" EnvelopeId="1A7BCB46-E398-41AA-ACD1-18BCD2C1E9C5" RecipientType="Signer" UserId="78C3E1DA-085A-45A0-9BCF-1DCDDBC48158" AccountId="5CB10BDC-1DAB-4CA7-A2E7-BEB2AEA280CB" Email="striderwho@hotmail.com" UserName="Jen Cheung" CompanyName="ServiceRocket" JobTitle="" SignatureImageId="" InitialsImageId="" AccessCodeRequired="False" IDCheckRequired="False" Sent="Sent: 10/15/2015 10:58:03 AM" Delivered="" Signed="" Declined="" DeclineReason="" Status="Sent" IPAddress="" SigningGroupName="" SigningGroupUsers="" SignedOnMobile="" AccountEsignId="" RoutingOrder="1" InPersonID="" WetSigned="no" Offline="false" SignatureImageHash="" InitialsImageHash="" SecurityLevel="Email, Account Authentication (None)" RecipientSuppliesTabs="true" ExternalUserName="" ExternalCompanyName="" CustomField1="##SFUser:00528000001Jds1AAC:Jen Cheung" CustomField2="" CustomField3="" /></Recipients><FormFields /><EnvelopeCustomFields><EnvelopeCustomField Name="DSXPartnerApplication" Value="DSFS 3.10" Required="False" Show="False" /><EnvelopeCustomField Name="PlatformName" Value="Salesforce" Required="False" Show="False" /><EnvelopeCustomField Name="AppName" Value="DocuSignForSalesforce" Required="False" Show="False" /><EnvelopeCustomField Name="DSFSSourceObjectId" Value="800280000000qON~Contract" Required="False" Show="False" /><EnvelopeCustomField Name="##SFContract" Value="800280000000qON" Required="False" Show="False" /><EnvelopeCustomField Name="##SFAccount" Value="00128000008iNC0AAM" Required="False" Show="False" /><EnvelopeCustomField Name="Company" Value="DocuSign" Required="False" Show="False" /></EnvelopeCustomFields></Certificate>
10/15/2015 10:58:24 AM
SalesForceIntegration failed, Salesforce User: jen@jenscompany.com, message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I've tried a whole number of config changes and can't seem to get rid of that error. And nothing is appearing in the Status section of the Contract object in Salesforce.

Does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: I believe it's a known bug on the DocuSign side that is actively being worked. Can you try turning off attachments in your connect configuration, if I'm correct then you will stop seeing the error? If that does not help, then it is another issue.

Comment: This is nearly 12 months old and it doesn't look like that bug is fixed yet. I'm having the same issue and all I want to do is update a record Status based on the response.